# How to get all the child Windows of a current Page in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have got this situation: I have a page from which I can open multiple windows. Are there any way to detect all the windows from the current page?

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
foreach (Window w in this.OwnedWindows)
                MessageBox.Show(w.Name.ToString());
```

while displaying child windows set the owner property.